# How to get an array's length which is returned by a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables

I know that I can get an array's length easily as shown here:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.length;
```

But in my datatables object it returns a constant value 1.

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
            bFilter : false,
            bPaginate: false
});
```

When I write the expression below in my Chrome console in runtime it returns the value 1:

```
table.row().length;
1
```

But if I write just this:

```
table.row();
```

It shows this:

```
[Array[2]
0: 0
1: 1
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]]
```

Why do they show different values?

Comment: Highlight: **[**Array[2]

Comment: You are not getting a single _Array_ returned, you're getting an _Array_ within an _Array_. The outer _Array_ has _length `1`_, the inner _Array_ has _length `2`_.

Comment: @PaulS. Thanks now I understand. I see you answer is deleted. If you add it I can accept as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting a single *Array* returned, you're getting an *Array* within an *Array*. The outer *Array* has *length `1`*, the inner Array has *length `2`*.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly .row() return an array of array (don't ask me why).

So to access your rows number, just do :

```
table.row()[0].length;
```